# Add options to select from JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

I need to get possible options for select from another server, so I use AJAX, as result I get json and `response.experience` looks like

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="experience" id="experience"></select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/',
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response.experience);

        $.each(response.experience, function (key, value) {
            $('#experience')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", key)
                    .text(value));
        });
    });
```

But after `append` I get object Object in options

[image]

How to create options in my case? And how to add attr `selected` for the first option?

Comment: $.each first argument is your index and second argument is your obj. so you need to get it by value.id or value.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$.each` for going through an array, use [`array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead like this:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/',
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response.experience);
        // using map
        $('#experience').append(
            response.experience.map(function (obj) {
                return $("<option/>")
                    .attr("value", obj.id)
                    .text(obj.name));
            })
        );
        // using forEach
        response.experience.forEach(function (obj) {
            $('#experience')
                .append(
                    $("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", obj.id)
                        .text(obj.name)
                );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you give me an example with `forEach` please?  And how to add attr `selected` for the first option?

Comment: @Heidel I have added `forEach` example, but consider using `map` because that one is more efficient solution, as it makes only one modification to the DOM

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in mind! I've tried to use your code with `map` but something is wrong with ) or } at the end of function but I can't understand what a problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:You are almost close to the solution.Please replace `value`by`value.name` in the option attributes.Here is the working code.

```
   $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/',
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response.experience);

        $.each(response.experience, function (key, value) {
            $('#experience')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value.name)
                    .text(value.name));
        });
    });
```

Comment: from the given ajax response, what should be present in the select options.I could see name,id,etc.,If `name` then use `value.name`.I have updated my answer please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the array which contains object and you are appending the objects to the select list. You may need to append one of the key of the object, example : 'id'.
And the call back function of `$.each` function will accept two parameters, current index and value. The first parameter will be always index.
Edit your ajax code as below :

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/',
})
.done(function (response) {
    console.log(response.experience);

    $.each(response.experience, function (index,value) {
        $('#experience')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value.id) //To append id of the json object to select list
                .text(value.id));
    });
    $('#experience').val(response.experience[0].id) // To add the selected attribute for the first option
});
```